# ¿Cómo decodificar los elementos de un JSON en PHP?

Tags: php, json

Tengo una pregunta, creo que sencilla estoy tratando de decodificar datos de un JSON que obtengo desde un URL(API), pero al momento de meterlos a un array y quererlos decodificar me marcar el sig. error

> Warning: Undefined array key "Nombre" in C:\xampp\htdocs\BD-DAEI\Conecct.php on line 45

```
$head = curl_init();
$url1 = "http://bdd-elga-01.signsle4u.xyz/apii.php";
curl_setopt($head, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
//Metodo de conexion al servidor remoto 
curl_setopt($head, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
//Verifica la seguridad del sitio remoto (http o hhtps)
curl_setopt($head, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//Establece la aceptacion de respuesta del servidor remoto  
curl_setopt($head, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result33 = curl_exec($head); 
$array4 = json_decode($result33,true); 
curl_close($head);
echo "Tu continente de Servidor es: " .$array4['Data']['Nombre'];
```

Si los estoy metiendo en un arreglo no se por que no me da el resultado que quiero.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

te cuento que la forma en la que decodificas el `json` es correcta, tu error esta básicamente en la forma en la que accedes a sus propiedades una vez decodificado.

Te explico, pude notar que este **endpoint** al cual solicitas datos, te retorna algo como esto:

```json
{
   "Data":[
      {
         "Nombre":"El rap es esto",
         "Artista":"Duo Kie",
         "Fecha":"2004"
      },
      {
         "Nombre":"El tiempo escapa",
         "Artista":"Nach",
         "Fecha":"2005"
      },
      {
         "Nombre":"Grandes Planes",
         "Artista":"CPV",
         "Fecha":"1998"
      },
      {
         "Nombre":"kilos",
         "Artista":"Frank T",
         "Fecha":"2001"
      },
      {
         "Nombre":"Pruebalo",
         "Artista":"SFDK",
         "Fecha":"2007"
      }
   ]
}
```

Lo que quiere decir que al parsearlo a un **Array asociativo** quedaría como:

```php
[
    "Data" => [
        [
            "Nombre" => "El rap es esto", 
            "Artista" => "Duo Kie", 
            "Fecha" => "2004" 
        ], 
        [
            "Nombre" => "El tiempo escapa", 
            "Artista" => "Nach", 
            "Fecha" => "2005" 
        ], 
        [
            "Nombre" => "Grandes Planes", 
            "Artista" => "CPV", 
            "Fecha" => "1998" 
        ], 
        [
            "Nombre" => "kilos", 
            "Artista" => "Frank T", 
            "Fecha" => "2001" 
        ], 
        [
            "Nombre" => "Pruebalo", 
            "Artista" => "SFDK", 
            "Fecha" => "2007" 
        ] 
    ] 
];
```

Entonces al acceder como `$array4['Data']['Nombre']` estás accediendo a un **índice** `Nombre` dentro de `Data` que no existe, ya que `Data` es un **Array multidimensional** y cada uno de esos **Arrays** si contiene ese índice `Nombre` que buscas.

La solución es iterar cada uno de esos **Arrays** con un `foreach` por ejemplo:

```php
// Iteramos el Array multidimensional bajo el alias $item
foreach($array4['Data'] as $item){
    
    // Imprimimos el índice 'Nombre'
    echo $item['Nombre'] . "<br>";

}
```